# Is Web3 on Python hosted on a Raspberry Pi possible?

Tags: web3.py, python, raspberry-pi

I've created a Discord bot that allows users to calculate their net worth including altcoins and LP tokens, which I want to use web3 to determine the value of. I did the standard `pip install web3` on Python 3.6.1. I'm using a Raspberry Pi 3b.

I'm doing `from web3 import Web3` to import, but this immediately raises `ValueError: int string too large to convert`. I determined it's the import causing this error by slowly commenting out everything else.

Is it just not possible to run Web3 on a Raspberry Pi because of the 32bit OS and Python install or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you have the whole stack trace?

Comment: The ValueError is the entire trace, because the error occurs when loading the module into discord.py. Nothing else shows up in the console other than that.